# How to correctly implement template-based access to EEPROM

Tags: templates, embedded

I'm working on an embedded device and need to save/read application settings to/from non-volatile memory, ie. an EEPROM chip. This EEPROM chip stores bytes, so in order to store application settings which are larger than a byte (float, uint32, objects..) I wrote dedicated save/read functions for each data type, eg save32, readFloat, etc.

**Now I want to try doing this using templates**. So I started with the following templated member functions:

```cpp
    template <typename dataType>
    static void save(settingIndex theIndex, const dataType& data);
    template <typename dataType>
    static dataType read(settingIndex theIndex);
```

In the implementation of these functions, I somehow need to convert the template type 'dataType' to bytes, because towards the EEPROM I can only write bytes..

```cpp
    static void read(uint32_t startAddress, uint8_t* data, uint32_t dataLength);         // low-level I2C reading from EEPROM
    static void write(uint32_t startAddress, uint8_t* data, uint32_t dataLength);        // low-level I2C writing to EEPROM
```

What would be a correct / preferred way to do this ?

Option 1: casting pointers from *dataType to *uint8_t, eg.

```cpp
template <typename dataType>
void settingsCollection::save(settingIndex theIndex, const dataType& dataIn) {
    uint8_t* bytePtr      = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&dataIn);
    ...
    nonVolatileStorage::write(startAddress, bytePtr, length);
}
```

But this leads to a linker problem:

```
undefined reference to `void settingsCollection::save<unsigned char>(settingsCollection::settingIndex, unsigned char const&)'
```

Option 2: via a union

```cpp
template <typename dataType>
void settingsCollection::save(settingIndex theIndex, const dataType& dataIn) {
    union {
        dataType dataIn;
        uint8_t bytesOut[sizeof(dataType)];
    } sourceDataUnion{dataIn};
    ...
    nonVolatileStorage::write(startAddress, &sourceDataUnion.bytesOut, length);
}
```

Unfortunately leading to (same ?) linker problem

```
undefined reference to `void settingsCollection::save<unsigned char>(settingsCollection::settingIndex, unsigned char const&)'
```

Here's how I tried to test it:

```cpp
void test_write_read_setting() {
    uint8_t testbyte{123};
    settingsCollection::save<uint8_t>(settingsCollection::settingIndex::nvsMapVersion, testbyte);
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_UINT8(testbyte, settingsCollection::read<uint8_t>(settingsCollection::settingIndex::nvsMapVersion));

    uint32_t testDoubleWord{0x55AA00FF};
    settingsCollection::save<uint32_t>(settingsCollection::settingIndex::uplinkFrameCounter, testDoubleWord);
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_UINT32(testDoubleWord, settingsCollection::read<uint32_t>(settingsCollection::settingIndex::uplinkFrameCounter));
}
```

So I'm a bit lost how to do this correctly.

Comment: OT: Your parameter `dataIn` is a reference, not a pointer. You need to add `&` in the cast, AFAIK.

Comment: thank you, but I think the & you refer to is already there : `uint8_t* bytePtr      = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&dataIn);`

Comment: Well, it was not in the version at the time I wrote the comment. ;-)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to show us how you use the templated class and to reproduce the linker errors.

Comment: ok, sorry about that, I tried to simplify the variable names to make it easier to read. Anyway, a mismatch like you mention would result in a compiler error, but the code compiles, it goes wrong at the linker stage..

Comment: ok, I added the unittest that is calling those functions to the question above.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not a [mre]. There is no command line to compile and link, and the unittest lacks `#include`s and possibly its `main()`. A [mre] provide **all** source code to reproduce without the need to invent the missing parts.

Comment: Concerning the linker error: Are you aware that you need to place the implementation of the templated methods in the header file? The compiler needs to see its implementation together with the specific usage to be able to generate necessary machine code. The linker will remove all duplicates.

Comment: nope - was not aware of that. This indeed solved my problem. Only the approach with casting the pointer is compiling, but I will look into the 'union' as well, and see if I can get it working. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: About the minimal reproducible example.. I was working on that, but the code is part of a big project in a IDE dedicated to embedded development, so it's not so easy to extract the minimal part... However, in the mean time your suggestion solved it, so thanks again. Looks like I still have to learn a lot about template functions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the implementation of the templated functions were in the .cpp file, io. of in the .h header file.

Kudos to [the busybee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11294831/the-busybee)

Comment: Yeah, the template system of C++ is kind of brain-damaged. :-D At least, if you understood the module system, how linkers work underneath the language. I'm glad to be able to help you.